# React Native IOS Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

[image]After I updated to React Native 0.73.3, I started to encounter this error when I build my project for IOS.

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The thing is, that when I build for Android, everything works perfect.

I tried:

```
 1. Cleaning build
 2. Rebuilding project
 3. Cleaning DerivedData
 4. Reinstalling pods
 5. Reinstalling dependencies for the whole project (using npm)
 6. Setting "arm64" as excluded architecture
```

I would really appreciate to receive help, because I've been trying to fix this for a week!